# Magento keeping old category url keys after re-name

Tags: category

After installing a Magento 1.9 that came with a theme pre-configured, I started to customize the category names from the placeholders. However, after renaming titles and erasing old url keys, the front end shows new titles but links to the old url keys no matter how many times I try to change them. The backend always shows the correct keys though.

I've flushed cache plenty of times, re-indexed plenty of times, but these place holder url keys remain. It's no local caching as it happens on other computers.

Are there any database tables I can check that might have the old values? I know of the url re-write table, but that technically shouldn't be affecting this, should it?

Comment: Are you doing this in default scope?

Answer (score 2):

The url rewrites are saved to the core_url_rewrite table. If you are still in development and not live you could probably just truncate that table and reindex the urls, for SEO reasons you wouldn't want to do that on a production site. Make sure you make a backup of the table before you do it though, just to be safe.

Comment: I thought Re-indexing URL Rewrite would do the same thing. Now I know how to deal with it. Thanks!